# Keras.backend.gradients giving None instead of Zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I am new to tensorflow and I am trying to get the second derivative of a function, however if the first derivative becomes constant the second derivative becomes None instead of 0.

From my understanding this is because there is no computational graph linking the constant from the first derivative to any of the variables, thus it becomes "None". But I do not understand how to fix this. I also don't understand why the derivative in such case isn't always 0, mathematically it makes more sense to set it to 0 instead of None.

Here's the code I'm running to get the issue:

```
x_val = np.linspace(0,1,n)
x = K.variable(x_val,dtype='float64',name='x')

y_val = np.linspace(0,1,n)
y = K.variable(y_val,dtype='float64',name='y')

z = x**2 + y + 1

g = K.gradients(z,[x,y])
g2 = K.gradients(g,[x,y])

print(K.eval(g2[0])) #Works
print(K.eval(g2[1])) #Gradient is None, can't be evaluated
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the `g2` as follows:

```
g2_correct = [g2_elem if g2_elem is not None else K.zeros_like(var) for var, grad_2 in zip(vars, g2)]
```

Reference:

- [Gradient computation erroneously returns None](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/783) - Answer by `joshburkart`

Comment: Thank you! This worked (after I changed grad_2 to g2_elem).
Do you know if this messes up the computational graph or something. Bascially, can this give me problems further down the line?

Comment: Also, do you know if this runs in parallel? From the looks of it that for loop won't run in parallel, I would very much like my code to run in parallel :P

Comment: For the computational graph part, I'm not sure whether it can mess things up since it is a vector operation, in the layers `None` parts may still be meaningful. 
For the parallel run, you can search about the thing since I cannot give advice when I'm still working on to achieve being parallel run too.

Comment: I found out how to do basically the same thing in parallel, tensorflow has a "where" function which does this :D Don't know how I didn't find it earlier while searching for the answer to this question.